# How does evaluation in Haskell work, for expressions with constraints

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, evaluation, strictness

Suppose I write in GHCi:

```
GHCi> let x = 1 + 2 :: Integer
GHCi> seq x ()
GHCi> :sprint x
```

GHCi prints `x = 3` as naturally expected.

However,

```
GHCi> let x = 1 + 2
GHCi> seq x ()
GHCi> :sprint x
```

yields `x = _`

The sole difference between the two expressions are their types (`Integer` vs `Num a => a`). My question is what exactly happens, and why is seemingly `x` not evaluated in the latter example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that

```
let x = 1 + 2
```

defines a *polymorphic* value of type `forall a. Num a => a`, and that is something which evaluates similarly to a function.

Each use of `x` can be made at a different type, e.g. `x :: Int`, `x :: Integer`, `x :: Double` and so on. These results are not "cached" in any way, but recomputed every time, as if `x` were a function which is called multiple times, so to speak.

Indeed, a common implementation of type classes implements such a polymorphic `x` as a function

```
x :: NumDict a -> a
```

where the `NumDict a` argument above is added by the compiler automatically, and carries information about `a` being a `Num` type, including how to perform addition, how to interpret integer literals inside `a`, and so on. This is called the "dictionary-passing" implementation.

So, using a polymorphic `x` multiple times indeed corresponds to invoking a function multiple times, causing recomputation. To avoid this, the (dreaded) Monomorphism Restriction was introduced in Haskell, forcing `x` to be monomorphic instead. The MR is not a perfect solution, and can create some surprising type errors in certain cases.

To alleviate this issue, the MR is disabled by default in GHCi, since in GHCi we don't care that much about performance -- usability is more important there. This however causes the recomputation to reappear, as you discovered.

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning the dictionary passing going on.